# Error Msg = ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Tags: sql, oracle

Error Msg = ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Aggregation.REPORTING_POSITION_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > TO_DATE('2021-06-30 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') THEN 'FALSE' 
         ELSE 'TRUE' 
         WHEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Aggregation.REPORTING_POSITION_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > TO_DATE('2021-06-30 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') THEN 'FALSE' 
         ELSE 'TRUE' 
       END 
FROM HKLRR_UAT_USER.aggr_707884
```

Comment: Readability is a feature. Please study @Littlefoot answer not just because it offers a correct solution to the error but because it shows how to layout code so it is easy to read. Your future colleagues - and indeed your future self - will thank you for learning how to use case, indentation and other layout techniques to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

If you really write queries like this, no wonder you get errors. That's unreadable.

Though, when properly formatted and errors fixed (it is `WHEN` that was misplaced), it seems to be returning something. To test it, I created a dummy CTE and removed `Aggregation` and `HKLRR_UAT_USER` as I don't have those users.

```
SQL> WITH
  2     aggr_707884
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT '2021-09-11 12:22:33' reporting_position_date FROM DUAL)
  5  SELECT CASE
  6            WHEN TO_DATE (
  7                    TO_CHAR (
  8                       TO_DATE (REPORTING_POSITION_DATE,
  9                                'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
 10                       'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
 11                    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >
 12                 TO_DATE ('2021-06-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
 13            THEN
 14               'FALSE'
 15            WHEN TO_DATE (
 16                    TO_CHAR (
 17                       TO_DATE (REPORTING_POSITION_DATE,
 18                                'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
 19                       'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
 20                    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >
 21                 TO_DATE ('2021-06-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
 22            THEN
 23               'FALSE'
 24            ELSE
 25               'TRUE'
 26         END result
 27    FROM aggr_707884
 28  /

RESUL
-----
FALSE

SQL>
```

---

I don't know why you nested that many `TO_DATE`/`TO_CHAR` functions; code could be shortened to

```
SQL> WITH
  2     aggr_707884
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT '2021-09-11 12:22:33' reporting_position_date FROM DUAL)
  5  SELECT CASE
  6            WHEN TO_DATE (REPORTING_POSITION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >
  7                 TO_DATE ('2021-06-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  8            THEN
  9               'FALSE'
 10            WHEN TO_DATE (REPORTING_POSITION_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >
 11                 TO_DATE ('2021-06-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
 12            THEN
 13               'FALSE'
 14            ELSE
 15               'TRUE'
 16         END result
 17    FROM aggr_707884
 18  /

RESUL
-----
FALSE

SQL>
```

---

Finally, as it seems you're repeating `WHEN` conditions (so remove one of them) and presuming that `reporting_position_date` column's datatype is `DATE` (it should be; don't store date values as strings), it becomes as simple as

```
SQL> WITH aggr_707884 AS (SELECT SYSDATE reporting_position_date FROM DUAL)
  2  SELECT CASE
  3            WHEN REPORTING_POSITION_DATE > DATE '2021-06-30' THEN 'FALSE'
  4            ELSE 'TRUE'
  5         END result
  6    FROM aggr_707884;

RESUL
-----
FALSE

SQL>
```

Comment: hi Littlefoot, it works fine. you made it done